# Overwrite inline - styling with css

Tags: html, css

I have an elements with

```
<div class="item" style="transform: translate3d(0px, -215px, 0px);">
 <a href="img.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="img.jpg"></a></div>
```

styling.

What I **need** to do is to get rid of inline style of element and overwrite it with media queries css. Is something like that possible or do I need to do it with javascript?

Comment: use `!important` in your css.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the `style` attribute from that tag completely and move the styles it contains to a stylesheet? Or do you mean you want/have to keep the `style` attribute but want to override it from your stylesheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `!important` here

```css
div.item {
  transform: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" style="transform: translate3d(0px, -215px, 0px);"> <a href="img.jpg" data-lightbox="one"><img src="img.jpg">lorem</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `!important` in your rules, and then then will override inline styles.
See [W3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules)